# Openlayers: select a feature programmatically

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I am working on a project that uses openlayers to display a WFS layer(GeoJSON format), I have no problem reading the GeoJSON and display features, but I want to select a feature programmatically, for example, there is a table displaying all the features attributes, when I click a row from the table, I want to select or highlight a specific feature on the map using the ID(or other properties) in that row.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, look up your feature:

myFeature=myVectorLayer.getFeaturesByAttribute("myAttribute","myValue")[0]

Then call .select(myFeature) on your [selectControl](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html).